# How to cast mock object to original CLR object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, casting, moq

I have a code in my .cs file like below

```
public IfileGroup Placefile(int quantity, IFileGroup destfile, ILoc location)
{    
    fileGroup fg = null;
    cg = this.TransferFile(quantity, destfile as FileGroup, location);
}
```

So In my test file I created mock object like this

```
Mock< IFileGroup > frp = new Mock< IFileGroup >();
frp.Setup(x => x.FileInfo).Returns("FileAvailable");
Mock<ILoc> locationMock;
locationMock.Setup(x => x.FileLocationId).Returns("10");
```

and calling the function

```
FileGroup target = new FileGroup ();    
var result = target.Placefile(4, frp.Object, locationMock.Object);
```

but while debugging, when control goes to  function `Placefile` it passes `destfile` as null, is there any way to down cast from mock object to original CLR object?

Answer (score 0):

Since the mock implements `IFileGroup` and does not inherit from `FileGroup`, there is no way to cast it.

Only if your `FileGroup` class were abstract or provides virtual methods, can you create a mock that can be cast to a `FileGroup`. This is basic .NET Inheritance for you.

Instead, your code should not rely on `FileGroup`, but should always rely on `IFileGroup` instead. So the call to `TransferFile` should look like:

```
 this.TransferFile(quantity, destfile as IFileGroup, location);
```

I suspect you may need to update the signature of `TransferFile` for that to work.  Or instead create a new `FileGroup` object instead of casting, as the cast isn't guaranteed to work:

```
 this.TransferFile(quantity, new FileGroup(destfile), location);
```

It's not the Mocking or the Casting that needs changing, you need to further refactor your API in order for it to be really testable.